# A slight deviation in pixel result

Tags: java, coordinates, pixel

Found this code on the web.
I insert my width and height properties of the picture, but for some reason I get a slight deviation at width result in pixels.
For coordinates(35.207887,32.104750) I am getting a result of 844x171 in pixels after running the code.
 Hence I concluded that deviation is at width parameter of the picture (the height is negligible, as it seems the differene range is only 2 pixels).
However using ms paint app. The actual result should be 795x169
The height however seems to be fine.
I would want to be directed to the specific point in the code, where the deviation is happening

```
package gis;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Map {

/**
 * width and height are the map bounds in pixels
 */

final int width=1433;
final int height=642;

public void getXYfromLatLon(double latitude, double longitude) {
    // get x value
    int mapWidth = 1433, mapHeight = 642;
    int pX = (int)((longitude+180.)*(mapWidth/360.));

    // convert from degrees to radians
    double latRad = latitude*Math.PI/180.;

    // get y value
    double mercN = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI/4.)+(latRad/2.)));
    int pY = (int)((mapHeight/2.)-(mapWidth*mercN/(2.*Math.PI)));
    String str="x = "+pX+", y = "+pY;
    System.out.println(str);
    //System.out.println("x = "+pX+", y = "+pY);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    /////////
    Map m=new Map();

    double latitude    = 35.207895; 
    double longitude   = 32.104740;   
    m.getXYfromLatLon(latitude, longitude);
//  getXYfromLatLon(latitude, longitude);

    /*latitude    = 30.0; // (ֿ†)
    longitude   = 34.0;   // (־»)
    getXYfromLatLon(latitude, longitude);*/
}


 }
```

Comment: I can direct you here instead: [ask]

Comment: @TimCastelijns What do you want from me?

Comment: What deviation? What width and height? Unclear what your asking for. Please produce a clear problem statement

Comment: I want you to read a little bit about how this site works before you go and post some vague question that basically says "I copied this code from internet but it doesn't work, please fix it for me"

Comment: There are several important assumptions about the map built into the code. One of them is that the map image shows longitudes from exactly -180° to +180° without any overlap/margin etc. You need to specify more clearly what you mean with "deviation" - a constant offset, linear error, rounding effect...

Comment: @Tim cas... This code works with an exception to width parameter as it is written " I get a slight deviation at width result in pixels".Second, I didn't ask you for solution, but to pinpoint more or less(in this case as it seems "less") to the problematic part

Comment: @Hulk ok I get what youre saying. I'll edit mo code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The math in the code is ok. Simple tests reveal that the right width pixel is calculated:

```
    latitude = 30.0; //
    longitude = -180; // --> 0 
    longitude = 0; // --> 716 
    longitude = 180; // --> 1433 
    m.getXYfromLatLon(latitude, longitude);
```

So the problem is that the map (ie the contents of your image file) is not exact. It is not easy to project a globe on a plane...